How can I return to my session if the login screen is not working?
When using a particular Thunderbolt dock, I wake my machine from sleep and sometimes I can't log in.
I see the normal login screen, I can move the cursor and type my password, but hitting Enter or clicking the submit button does nothing.
It doesn't tell me my password was wrong or even look like it's trying to authenticate.
The UI remains interactive but does not perform its function.
The issue is like this one, but I'm not on Arch.
The login screen ‘goes to sleep’ after a very short period, and seems to struggle to resume after moving the cursor or pressing a key.
I'd rather not restart SDDM because that wipes out the current session, losing my place and any unsaved work.

I switched to a virtual terminal with Ctrl + Alt + F4, logged in and looked at running processes with this:
ps -ef | less -niS

I saw the process below, and remembered something about the lock screen not being the same as the log in prompt for beginning a new session, which is provided by SDDM.
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kscreenlocker_greet --immediateLock --graceTime 5000 --ksldfd 138

I used kill with the kscreenlocker_greet's process ID (the default TERM signal), then switched back to login screen's TTY.
I think it had moved from TTY 2 to 1.
I went back and forth again to confirm its PID had changed.
I was then able to log in, and all my programs were still running.
